# What causes barakat to go away?

Tags: allah, spirituality

> Barakah... is a kind of continuity of spiritual presence and revelation that begins with God and flows through that and those closest to God. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barakah)

In general, it's given that all type of neglections in obligations by Muslim person would cause barakats to go away. But has been listed as especial effect. Such as not praying on 5 times, disrespecting food, not giving to poor, staying nude in home, etc...

But I don't know all. Could you provide a list of all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate

Our daily actions determine to a large degree whether barakat (blessing, plentiful) will enter our life or it goes out of our life. If we obey almighty Allah, he will bless us with his kindness. Here some of the actions which increase or remove barakat are listed.

1-We are informed to avoid getting money from cruel and irreligious people, because this money will not have barakat for us and it will disturb our life. Imam Ja'far as-Sadiq (a.s.) says:

> "Fear Allah, strengthen your faith with an incomparable taqayya and
>   avoid presenting your needs to the ruler. And if a person is
>   respectful to an irreligious man, Allah will degrade him and will
>   consider him His enemy and leave him on his own. And if he receives
>   any monetary benefit from this man, Allah will remove barakat from it.
>   And if he uses this money to perform Hajj or emancipate slaves, or for
>   any other benevolent deed, he will not get any reward for it."(Al
>   Kafi)

2-Acquiring knowledge for show-off is said to remove barakat. Our Holy Prophet of Islam (s.a.w.s.), in his advice to Ibne Masud said:

> “One who acquires knowledge for show-off, Allah will take away Barakat
>   (blessings), make his economic affairs difficult and leave him to his
>   devices; and one whom He leaves to his devices will be destroyed

3-According to another hadith, abusing a believer brother will remove blessing (barakat) from our life:

> “If one abuses his brother in faith, Allah removes barakat (blessing)
>   from his sustenance, leaves him to his devices and destroys his
>   life.”Al-Kafi, Vol. 2, Pg. 325, Tr. 13

4-Muslims life style is set so that, barakat enter his life. For example for eating food we are advised not to dry washed hands using towel. The hadith from Imam Sadiq (a.s.) says:

> “One who washes his hands should not dry them with a towel, because
>   till wetness remains, there is barakat in food.Makarimul Akhlaq, Pg. 139, other tradition also with the same context is in Al-Kafi, Vol. 6, Pg. 291

5-In another hadith we are informed by Imam Sadiq (a.s) from Holy Prophet (s.a.w.s.):

> “May Allah give barakat to one who takes easy buying, selling, justice
>   and accepting the judgment"

6-Recitation of Holy Quran book is said to increase barakat. In this context we are informed that Iman Sadiq (a.s.) says that Amirul Momineen (a.s.) said:

> “The house in which Quran is recited and remembered, its blessings
>   increase, angels come there, satans go away and that house gives light
>   to folks of the sky as stars give light to the dwellers of the earth
>   and surely that house, where Quran is not recited, its barakat is
>   reduced, angels go away from there and Satans comes there.Al-Kafi, Vol. 2, Pg. 498

I hope my answer is helpful!